# Magento 2 - checkout - iframes and firefox - browser history back button

Tags: magento2, checkout, iframe

While being in Checkout and having an iFrame on /checkout/#payment page, by trying to get back to previous page checkout/#shipping by using the browser back button the content of checkout/#shipping is loaded in my iFrame and the page URL is still consisting as /checkout/#payment instead of checkout/#shipping.

I've to reload this page twice to get to checkout/#shipping.
This is only happening in FireFox. 
Functionality of browser history back is working for Chrome and Safari fine, but not for Firefox.